# Magento: edit message if i could find it

Tags: jquery, magento

I am using Magento and have a message that pops up, but I can't find where I can edit this message that the code is generating below. Can anyone help me?

```
function showMessage(message)
    {
        jQuery('body').append('<div class="alert"></div>');
        var $alert = jQuery('.alert');
        $alert.slideDown(400);
        $alert.html(message).append('<button></button>');
        jQuery('button').click(function () {
            $alert.slideUp(400);
        });
        $alert.slideDown('400', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $alert.slideUp('400', function () {
                    jQuery(this).slideUp(400, function(){ jQuery(this).detach(); })
                });
            }, 7000)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if I understand your question correctly, you want to know where `showMessage()` is called in that specific page, because there is where you can see the `message` param..and so you will be able to edit it.

If this is the case, I suggest you to enable the **Template Path Hints** feature, in order to explicitly see all the blocks (and corresponding template files) involved in the creation of the page, and you will be able to find the message.

Log into the admin section, *System -> Configuration -> Developer*.
Click on **Debug**.

Now you have to change the value of *Current Configuration Scope* (upper left) from **default** to your specific website.
At this point the **Template Path Hints** option appears, and you can check **yes**. You can also use **Add Block Names to Hints** in order to see the model class for the a block.

Comment: Brilliant and a great help. I found it.